# Unexpected exit after user input

Tags: batch-file

Need a little help here for my code.

When the script detects save-file it needs to ask whether to re-create it. At this point, I click on `Y` for `Yes`, but it `exit`s.

Here's the code:

```
:existing
echo Welcome to Androids: Became Human!
echo ==================================
echo.
echo It appears that you already created
echo configuration file. Would you like
echo to re-create it?
echo.
echo Please enter (Y,N):
set /p choice=
if %choice% == "y" goto welcome
if %choice% == "n" exit
if %choice% == "Y" goto recreation
if %choice% == "N" exit
```

Comment: I don't see any label called `recreation` in your file, though you reference it in the second-last line

Comment: Oops. I'm sorry. I didn't change that before posting. Thank you tho. :)

Comment: Can you please explain why you accepted an answer that doesn't work and did not leave feedback at least to the other answers?

Comment: @double-beep 'Cause it works for me atleast. ;)

Comment: @RichardLucin you selected the first way which works, but the second doesn't. My answer has both ways which work. Also, note that you accept answers for future readers, not for people; the answer you have accepted has no explanations and the author may copied it from other answers without credits.

Comment: Now that you have earned the required privilege, consider upvoting some answers here and in your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use quotes on both sides, here is an example:

**BAD:**

```
:existing
echo Welcome to Androids: Became Human!
echo ==================================
echo.
echo It appears that you already created
echo configuration file. Would you like
echo to re-create it?
echo.
echo Please enter (Y,N):
set /p choice=
if %choice% == "y" goto welcome
if %choice% == "n" exit
if %choice% == "Y" goto recreation
if %choice% == "N" exit
```

**GOOD:**

```
:existing
echo Welcome to Androids: Became Human!
echo ==================================
echo.
echo It appears that you already created
echo configuration file. Would you like
echo to re-create it?
echo.
echo Please enter (Y,N):
set /p choice=
if "%choice%" == "y" goto welcome
if "%choice%" == "n" exit
if "%choice%" == "Y" goto recreation
if "%choice%" == "N" exit
```

Also here I have made a better version of your code:

```
:existing
echo Welcome to Androids: Became Human!
echo ==================================
echo.
choice /c ynY /cs /m "It appears that you already created the configuration file, would you like to save it"
cls
if "%errorlevel%" == "1" goto welcome
if "%errorlevel%" == "2" exit
if "%errorlevel%" == "3" goto recreation
```

Comment: The code will not work and throw a beep if user inputs N.

Comment: Wow, you made it even better! It actually is shorter and better. I knew there was choice command, but I forgot about it. xD Also, I didn't quite know how to use it anyways. Thank you!

Comment: @double-beep I don't know about you, but 'N' for me works flawlessly. It's not giving me any errors on my Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: @RichardLucin in cmd, type `choice /c ynY /cs /m "It appears that you already created the configuration file, would you like to save it"` and press enter. Then, press `N` - note that it is capital.

Comment: @double-beep Of course, in that case it will do not work. For that you shall use choice /c ynNY /cs /m "It appears that you already created the configuration file, would you like to save it" I added a capital "N" which worked for me. Maybe he just forgot to add that "N".

Comment: @RichardLucin you didn't even consider saying me if my answer works. **Note that he didn't forgot the `N`; he didn't test the code. Even if he add it and you press `N`, the batch file will exit**. Please re-consider accepting another answer.

Comment: @double-beep I consider this answer as my main, as It worked for me in other choices in the game. Such as: `choice /c 12 /cs /m "Please select: "
if "%errorlevel%" == 1 goto component5940
if "%errorlevel%" == 2 goto component4060
`

Comment: @RichardLucin so my answer didn't work for you? I don't think so. Have you seen `choice /?`? You don't seem to understand how it works.

Comment: Oh, and @double-beep, you need to remove `/cs` which enables case-sensivity which honestly worked for me just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you are including quotes **only in one side**, then ***the quotes are included in the comparison***. I wouldn't recommend neither removing the quotes from one side, which isn't safe, **nor** adding quotes to both sides like this (which also works good) [parenthesis included]:

```bat
:existing
echo Welcome to Androids: Became Human!
echo ==================================
echo.
echo It appears that you already created
echo configuration file. Would you like
echo to re-create it?
echo.
echo Please enter (Y,N):
set /p choice=
if "%choice%" == "y" (goto welcome)
if "%choice%" == "n" (exit)
if "%choice%" == "Y" (goto recreation)
if "%choice%" == "N" (exit)
```

Instead, I would go forward and entirely change your code using the `choice` command doing the following:

```bat
:existing
echo Welcome to Androids: Became Human!
echo ==================================
echo.
echo It appears that you already created
echo configuration file. Would you like
echo to re-create it?
echo.
choice /C:YyNn /CS /M "Please enter (Y,N):" /N
if errorlevel 3 (exit)
if errorlevel 2 (goto :welcome)
if errorlevel 1 (goto :recreation)
```

which is much sorter.

For more info about the commands used, open a new cmd and type:

- `echo /?`
- **`choice /?`**
- `if /?`